# flex programmatically show tooltip chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts, tooltip

I have a chart with 2 line series in it.

So, "Jan" (x-axis point) will have 2 Y-axis points

The problem :
**Is there anyway to force flex to show tooltip on both series simultaneously?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an article in the docs that discusses the use of multiple data tips in a chart: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_08.html

There's a section called "Showing multiple DataTip objects" about a third of the way down.  Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, but the issue now is-  the toottips popup for different x-axis points i.e. one toottip on (jan, y1), and other on (feb,y2).
I think the "mouseSensitivity" is causing close by points to show the tips. I just want all the y' axis points for a given x-axis point.

Also, if the points are not close by then the toot tips don't show up.